# What to return in the angular 2 async validator when using observables

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-observables

What do I have to return in the customerNameValidator if the

async validation fails/succeeds that my 'customerName' FormControl is invalid?

```
this.customerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
customerName: 
[this.newCustomerName, [Validators.minLength(2), Validators.required],[this.customerNameValidator.bind(this)]]
});


customerNameValidator(c: AbstractControl)
{
   return this.service.customerExists(c.value,this.companyId).subscribe(response =>
   {
        if(response == true)
        {
             alert("true");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("false");
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: An observable emitting the same thing as what a validator would return: null if no error, an object with error key(s) if there is an error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than subscribing, you should map the observable to change the result of the returning stream, rather than reading from it.

```
customerNameValidator(c: AbstractControl)
{
   return this.service.customerExists(c.value,this.companyId).map(response =>
   {
        if(response == true)
        {
            return { customerExists: true };
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
   });
}
```

Returning an object with a value that is true is how you should return the observable. You may be missing some important steps for async validators though, but because we don't gave all your code it's hard to say. [Try checking out this article](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-forms-create-async-validator-directive-dd3fd026cb45#.us2a17szf) or [this article](https://medium.com/@ttemplier/implementing-custom-validator-for-template-driven-forms-292eb355447c#.jabzfcok9) for more information.

Comment: just wonder how the new custom validator class would be implemented for Async Validation in FormBuilder? Thanks

Comment: @HungBui The same way as any other custom validator class would be implemented. Your validator should just be a function that gets passed into the form control. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Thanks @Adam - I'm looking at the first link that you provided, custom validatior was created as extended class of Validator class. However, the Validators.composeAsync() method was expecting a AsyncValidatorFn class object. Just wonder if there is away to convert a AsyncValidator to AsyncValidatorFn so it can be injected? Hope it makes sense.

Comment: You don't pass in the whole class to your validator, just specific functions. If your `Validator` class has the async functions `usernameAlreadyUsed` and `anotherAsyncFunction`, then you would pass that into the validator. Check out the [interface for `AsyncValidatorFn`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.8/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/validators.ts#L112-L119), all you need to do is pass in a control, which the validator does automatically.

Comment: @Adam - I can't add my sample code here so could you take a look at a separate answer and indication of how to pass it to the Validator would be great.

Comment: @Adam I guess in my case, it would just need pass validateUserObs function into Validators.composeAsync( [MyAsyncValidator.validateUserObs] )  ?

Comment: As a supplement, this `map` operator is from `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`, not the default one of JavaScript.

Answer (score 8):

I implemented an reactive form with an AsyncValidatorFn on angular 6.1.1. and would like to share some of my learning

I found out that angular does not (automatically) update the form control for AsyncValidatorFn as it does for internal sync validators .

so, as per the "AsyncValidatorFn" interface spec, you have to "manually" update your form control in your implementation of

```
(c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null>;
```

and then, you will check the control state in the html element

What I had implemented is an Username existence checking that might be very commonly found in an user sign-up process

below are the code excerpts:

the form control

```
 // Supports alphabets and numbers no special characters except underscore('_') and dash('-') min 3 and max 20 characters.
    this.userName = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9_-]{3,20}$')]),Validators.composeAsync([this.checkUser()]));
```

the custom async validator and the helper functions

```
checkUser (): AsyncValidatorFn{

    return (c: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
      return c
        .valueChanges
        .debounceTime(400)
        .mergeMap(value => this.gabriel.filter({'userName':value}))
        .map(stat => this.mapErr(c, stat));
    } 

  }

  private mapErr(c: AbstractControl, res: any): ValidationErrors{
    let err: ValidationErrors;
    switch (res['state']){
      case  0:
        err = null;
        break;
      case -100:
        err = {'existed': true};
        break; 
      case -1:
      default:
        err = {'failed': true};                      
    }
    c.setErrors(err);
    return err;
  }
```

note that I input the control as a parameter into the "mapErr" function, and set the control by "c.setErrors(err);".

the "return err;" statement return "ValidationErrors" as per the "AsyncValidatorFn" interface spec.

the "gabriel.filter()"queries the backend with the extracted username; and returns 0, -100, -1 respectively for "ok", "duplicated", and "operation failed"

```
  filter(json): Observable<{}>{
    let body = JSON.stringify(json);
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(Cons.filter, body, options).timeout(10000).map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
```

the control checking in html file

```
 <form [formGroup]="sf" (ngSubmit)="signin()">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>UserName</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" formControlName="userName" [class.invalid]="userName.dirty&&userName.invalid&&userName.errors!=null" ></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
            <p *ngIf="userName.dirty && userName.hasError('existed')">
              Username already existed
            </p>
            <p *ngIf="userName.dirty && userName.hasError('failed')">
              can not check validity of Username 
            </p>
```

I also found out that the async validators are not trigger until sync validator are satisfied in one form control.

in my case, I also used the built-in Validators.pattern to define a minimum length of 3.(see above Username formControl definition)

the custom async validator never triggers as long as my input length is shorter than 3.