# angular2 subscribe return value

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe

I do subscribe to a http request service in my `validateUsernameIsUnique` method. I am trying to manipulate the return value of `validateUsernameIsUnique()` based on the code inside the subscription. I did read some beginner articles about asynchronous behaviour. Therefore i know the code below is not working because `return ret;` is undefined. Unfortunatley i wasn't able to figure out how achieve what i am trying to do.

```
@Injectable()
export class ValidateService {

  constructor(private _authService: AuthService) { }

...

  validateUsernameIsUnique = (c: FormControl) => {

    let ret;
    if (c.value.length >= 3) {

        this._authService.uniqueUser({ username: c.value }).subscribe(data => {

          if (!data.success) {   // Username already exists       
            ret = { usernameIsTaken: true };          
          }
          else 
            ret = null;
        })

        return ret;
    }

  }

}
```

The Auth Service i am subscribing to looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  authToken: any;
  user: any;

  constructor(private _http: Http) { } 

  uniqueUser(user) {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/username', user, { headers: headers })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

**Update1:**

Changed code as mentioned in comments to

```
  validateUsernameIsUnique = (c: FormControl) => {        
    if (c.value.length >= 3) {     
      return this._authService.uniqueUser({ username: 'zomh' }).map(res =>          
      {             
        if (!res.success) {   // Username already exists              
          return { usernameIsTaken: true };    
        }
        else
        {

          return null;
        }
      });

    }

  }
```

And the Call looks like

```
ngOnInit() {        
      this.frmRegisterUser = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
      username: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, this._validateService.validateUsernameIsUnique, Validators.minLength(3), this._validateService.validateUsernamePattern]),
      email: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, this._validateService.validateEmailPattern]),
      password: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
      acceptTerms: new FormControl(false,[Validators.required])
    });
```

Now i am reciving an Object which looks like :
[image: Object]

Sorry but i still don't get it where can i find the mapped returning values e.g. `{ usernameIsTaken: true }`

**Update2**
@pixelbits

It did not work right off the bat: I don't know how to to debug this proper ?, since console.logs won't be printed for async reasons in the inner functions. I tried putting a username 'zomh' which is already in the db (not unique).

```
  uniqueName(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    console.log('i am here');
    return (control:AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationResult> => {

      let q = new Promise<ValidationResult>(
        (resolve, reject)=>  { 
            var name = 'zomh';
            if (name == '') {
              resolve(null);
            }
            else {

              this._authService.uniqueUser({ username: 'zomh' })
                .map(t=>t.json())
                .subscribe(response=> {
                    if (response.success === false) {

                      resolve(response);  
                    }

                      else 
                        resolve(null);

                });
            }
        });

        return q;
    }
  }
```

I am getting the `"i am here"` in console but thats pretty much it. I get null returned even though it shouldn't with an existing username. I can verifiy the AuthService is working correctly ( tested it with a basic subscribe and username 'zomh').

Comment: Your code doesn't work because `.subscribe` is asynchronous. Observables altogether are asynchronous, so you can't return their data outside of their scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to return in the angular 2 async validator when using observables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379203/what-to-return-in-the-angular-2-async-validator-when-using-observables)

Comment: I think you're mixing sync and async validators in the third parameter. The second parameter is for sync validators, the third paramter is for async validators. You need to separate them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you need to implement an asyncronous validator as a factory:

```
import {  AbstractControl, AsyncValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


interface ValidationResult {
 [key:string]:boolean;
}
@Injectable()
export class ValidationService {
   constructor(private _authService: AuthService)  {

  }
  validateUsernameIsUnique(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control:AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationResult> => {

      let q = new Promise<ValidationResult>(
        (resolve, reject)=>  { 
            var name = control.value;
            if (name == '') {
              resolve(null);
            }
            else {

              this._authService.uniqueUser({ username: control.value })
                //.map(t=>t.json()) // Auth Service already returning json
                .subscribe(response=> {
                    if (response.success === false) 
                        resolve({ usernameIsTaken: true });                  
                      else 
                        resolve(null);

                });
            }
        });


        return q;
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure you pass the validator as the third parameter (that's where async validators go, the second parameter is for synchronous validators)

```
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group( {
     'username': ['hello',, this.validationService.validateUsernameIsUnique()]
    });
```

Comment: Let me try to implement this. I am kinda beginner and most i see here is sorcery to me. I doubt i can ever get to a point understanding this :/. Thanks in advance though

Comment: Its a factory function, so it needs to be invoked - see updated answer.

Comment: Its working now i did edit 2 small things of your code. Big thanks i'll mark it as answer ofc. Still i have to learn some about factories and promises. Thank you!